# How to turn off Internet access of my app in iOS + Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, xctestcase

I have been writing Unit Test and UI Test in my app. I have completed the most part of it. The pending thing is the Network Retry view. This page will be called when there is no internet. Is there any way we can turn off internet access (WiFi) in runtime so that i can execute UI test cases to test this page? In other words, this page will be called in the dashboard if there is no internet. So for going to the dashboard, the app needs internet access(to login, etc). Once it goes to the dashboard, i should be able to turn of internet access from within my test case and then check the Network retry page.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Network Link Conditioner](https://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) to control the internet connection